# Simplemembership UserProfile returning NULL value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, simplemembership

What is wrong with this query, why is it not returning a User object for me. I can verify that the user is successfully created, I can see the record in the DB but I am unable to query for that object so I can use that newly created UserId as FK in another table.

```
[HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Attempt to register the user
                try
                {
                    WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password, new {AccountType = model.AccountType  }); 
                    WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password);

                    var userProfile = db.UserProfiles.Local.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == User.Identity.Name)
                    ?? db.UserProfiles.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == User.Identity.Name);

                    if (userProfile == null)
                    {
                        throw new Exception("no userProfile for this user");
                    }
                    if (userProfile.AccountType == AccountType.Retailer)
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Create", "Retailer");
                    }

                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
```

Here is the Enum for the AccountType

```
public enum AccountType
    {
        Retailer = 1,
        Customer = 2,
        Manager = 3,
        Employee = 4
    }
```

Thanks, I am looking for how retrieve either the UserProfile object or ID of a logged in user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using `User.Identity.Name`, try querying using `model.UserName`